# Uninstall Internet Explorer 8 and install Internet Explorer 6

Tags: internet-explorer, downgrade

How do I install Internet Explorer 6 as my default browser and remove Internet Explorer 8?

I need this because of the script in my course syllabus.

Comment: I need this too because my intranet apps don't work on IE8, I need to move back to IE6. Compatibility mode doesn't cut it either.

Comment: @alok, so what happened to IE7 then?

Comment: What exactly does your script need to do that requires IE6? I ask because there may be alternatives and I'd hate for you to get misleading answers because we misunderstood what you needed to do...

Comment: @Arjan IE8 compatibility mode is IE7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uninstalling IE8 on Windows XP

- Click the ‘Start’ Button –> ‘Control Panel’ –> ‘Add or Remove Programs’.
- Find and select Windows Internet Explorer 8 from the list of software, click on the ‘remove’ button.
- Restart Windows.

Removing IE8 on Windows Vista

- Click the ‘Start’ Button –> ‘Control Panel’ –> ‘Programs’ (Programs and Features)
- Select View installed updates
- Find and select Windows Internet Explorer 8 from the list of available updates, click uninstall.
- Restart Windows.

[image]

How to Reinstall Internet Explorer 6 or 7?

- After you restart your computer, open Internet Explorer. The icon is still on your desktop.
- In Internet Explorer, go to ‘Help’ –> ‘About Internet Explorer’
- If Internet Explorer 6 or 7 appears in the About Internet Explorer dialog box, then you’ve successfully uninstalled IE8.

Source:

> http://www.geckoandfly.com/2009/06/30/uninstall-windows-ie8-and-reinstall-internet-explorer-6-or-7/

Comment: will this work for window 7 ultimate ?

Answer (score 25):

Don't.

Seriously.

---

To clarify: It's okay to install IE6 for testing purposes or the like. But that's probably best done in the sandbox of a VM. Do *not* make IE 6 the default browser on your machine. Nothing good can come out of that.

Comment: Make it Community Wiki, then you don't get any upvotes.

Answer (score 16):

[IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) will do what you want ...

[image]

However I would have a talk with your lecturer.

I would have serious concerns with any course syllabus that requires downgrading back to a browser that was released in 2002, because what they are teaching would no longer be relevant.

The syllabus should be updated to use a current version that confirms with ECMA standards.

Comment: ...and, as such, should not only be independent on the version of Internet Explorer, but be independent on the browser and OS to start with.

Answer (score 13):

If you are working under Windows 7 or Vista then there is no possible way to do this.

If you have Windows XP you should be able to uninstall IE 7+ via the "Add / Remove Software"-panel.

If you want to emulate IE6 you can do so by setting the Developer Tools in IE8 (you can access these tools by pressing F12 or navigating to Tools > Developer Tools) to "Quirks Mode".

I recommend, that if reeeally need to use the real IE6 (for testing your websites or something), download the Virtual PC HD image of Windows XP SP3 with IE6 installed: http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en
and use it in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 8):

You can install a virtual machine (for example, [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox)) with either a stock Windows XP (which comes with Internet Explorer 6) or Linux (and install [IEs4linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page)).

Answer (score 5):

You can get all versions of Internet Explorer at *[Final Builds Site - IE Collection](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm)*
and have them installed at the same time, then choose your default
or try *[Browser Compatibility Check for Internet Explorer Versions from 5.5 to 10](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)*.

Comment: I would definitely recommend IETester as the way to go. It's free, easy to install, and doesn't mess with your system. Ideal.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on XP, you can install [Multiple IE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to go to the control panel - > Add Remove Programs

Find IE8 in the list and uninstall.  This should roll you back to version 7.  Go back to add/remove programs and uninstall IE one more time. This will roll you back to version 6.0
That is all there is to it!

Happy Hunting

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ThinApp (and possibly few other similar app virtualization softwares).

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1026565

http://blogs.vmware.com/thinapp/2010/06/internet-explorer-6on-windows-7.html

Comment: Link-only answers tend to become invalid when the pages they point to disappear.  Can you expand your answer?