# How to install IE6 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninstall IE8 and install IE6](https://superuser.com/questions/17480/uninstall-ie8-and-install-ie6)

Can anyone help me to install Internet explorer in Windows7.

Comment: Duplicate question - http://superuser.com/questions/17480/uninstall-ie8-and-install-ie6

Answer (score 6):

If you are running Windows 7 Professional or better, you can use the free Windows XP Mode to install IE6, or any other software requiring Windows XP.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

If you're running Home Premium or lower, you'll also need a Windows XP CD and license key to create a regular virtual machine installation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows Professional, Enterprise or Ultimate you can use Windows Virtual PC with Windows XP Mode for free available at microsoft site.

You can use, too, a VirtualBox virtual machine (free) and install windows XP on it.

**There is also available from microsoft, the VPC Hard Disk Images with different internet explorer versions on Windows XP and Vista available for free [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en).**

Answer (score 1):

You could use virtualisation for that. Create a xp machine in vmware for example and run ie6 from there. I always found this to be the ideal solution. It gives you access to tons of different environment to test your things on.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you need IE6 for you might be able to use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).